# Como pasar un dataset( tabla de mi base de datos) y crear objetos de cada fila C#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, .net

me encuentro haciendo un proyecto propio de una biblioteca de medios con forms en el ide visual studio
ya había creado un pequeña base de datos y pude hacer la relación y crear un data set con la info de la db
pero ahora deseo pasar casa fila a ser un objeto con el cual trabajar, ya que el programa va a mostrar toda la información almacenada en cada objeto de estos en una ventana nueva, estuve viendo por windows docs pero no encontre un ejemplo mas relacionado a lo que estoy haciendo.

```
DataSet1 DataSet1= new DataSet1();//creo el dataset vacio
DataSet1TableAdapters.MediaTableAdapter mediaTableAdapter =
new DataSet1TableAdapters.MediaTableAdapter();//instancio
mediaTableAdapter.FillMedia(DataSet1.Media);//lo lleno con la info de la db
```

de aqui necesitaria una guia, he visto ejemplos con listas pero no veo como llamar los objetos 1 por 1
este es la clase que manejp

```
 public class Media
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdMedia { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Pagina { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
```

Comment: por cierto mi conocimiento es limitado, se conceptos basicos de programacion pero apenas me encuentro aprendiendo de manera independiente

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama Entity Framework checa el siguiente video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkfpBeIiHYs para mas información https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/

Comment: gracias listo lo vere y actualizare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos espero que te sirva esto, en este código, tengo mi objeto CategoryObj el cual tiene 4 propiedades, tengo mi método que mando a llamar a la base de datos y lleno un objeto nuevo por cada fila y creo mi lista de objetos.

Aquí tengo mi objeto

```
Public Class CategoryObj

        Private _idcategory As Integer = -1
        Private _Category_ES As String
        Private _Category_EN As String
        Private _active As Boolean

        Public Property active As Boolean
            Get
                Return _active
            End Get
            Set(value As Boolean)
                _active = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Category_EN As String
            Get
                Return _Category_EN
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _Category_EN = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Category_ES As String
            Get
                Return _Category_ES
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _Category_ES = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property idcategory As Integer
            Get
                Return _idcategory
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _idcategory = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

Aqui tengo mi metodo que donde se llena una lista con los objetos

```
 Public Sub GetCategories(list_categories As List(Of CategoryObj))
            Try
                OpenDB("DB-EWEBSERVICES")
                SetCommand("Select idcategory, category_es, category_en,active from tbl_categories")
                SetDataAdapter()
                Dim dts As New DataSet
                connection.Adap.Fill(dts)
                If dts.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    If dts.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        For Each row As DataRow In dts.Tables(0).Rows
                            'Crea un nuevo objeto
                            Dim new_Category As New CategoryObj
                             'Llena objeto
                            new_Category.idcategory=row("idcategory");
                            new_Category.Category_ES=row("category_es");
                            new_Category.Category_En=row("category_en");
                            new_Category.active=row("active");

                            list_categories.Add(new_Category)
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            Finally
                CloseDB()

            End Try
        End Sub
```

lo uso así..

```
Dim ADOCategory as new ADOCateogry()
Dim ListObjetos as new List(Of CategoryObj)
ADOCategory.GetCategories(ListObjetos)
```

Comment: como no conozco por completo c# estoy leyendo como funciona alguna palabras reservadas que usas ahi, pero por lo que veo es preciso lo que necesito. en cuanto lo aplique al codigo que tengo lo confirmo

Answer (score 0):

al final me base en este video para hacer las relaciones y poder usar la base de datos.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7KZ_-iTUww&list=WL&index=8&t=87s
visualmente no me agrada y me queda algo complicado, pero da solucion a lo que buscaba para empezar.